# administrator page become blank after install jomsocial

Tags: joomla3.0, jomsocial

I have Joomla 3.0 and i install Jomsocial after it my administrator front page become blank in localhost. jomsocial provide me two zip folder one is com_community_pro_3.0.5.3 and iJoomla-Installer-Updater and i installed com_community_pro_3.0.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpMyAdmin => your_database => extensions_table => search_system_plugin_of_jomsocial => set_published_to 0.

Your site will be up again and JomSocial will not work untill you publish the system plygin again from Joomla Plugin manager/PHPMyAdmin.